# The number of times will an individual child goes to the cinema before a group is repeated.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, word-problem

> $1.)$ A mother with $7$ children takes $3$ at a time to a cinema.She goes with every 
>   group of $3$ that she can form.How many times can she go to cinema with
>   distinct groups of  $3$ children?
>
> $2.)$ For the above question , how many times will an individual child go to the 
>   cinema with her before a group is repeated?

For the $1$st question I think the answer is $\dbinom{7}{3}$

for the $2$nd one , I am simply unable to interpret the question 
though the answer given for question $2.)$ is $\dbinom{6}{2}$.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: Let Alicia be the individual child. There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose a group of three that includes Alicia. For there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the two other kids who will be with her.

Comment: Alternatively there are $\binom 7 3$ groups of three children before a repeat. That is $3\cdot \binom 73$ visits to the cinema altogether, distributed evenly between $7$ children so $\frac 37\cdot \binom 73=\binom 62$ visits for each child before a group is repeated.

Answer (score 2):

There are ${7\choose 3}=35$ different groups of three that can be formed. Realizing all of them means $35$ trips to the cinema, or $35\cdot3=105$ children's tickets. Since there are $7$ children each of them has visited the cinema ${105\over7}=15={6\choose 2}$ times, namely with every pair of his $6$ siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Part $1$ is correct.

Part $2$ is also correct. It can also be written and solved as the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^5i$$

Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

1st one is ok.

For the 2nd one, either consider that you must be attached to all groups of 2 from the remaining, hence ${6\choose2}$, or that you can only be in $\frac37$ of the 35 possible groups.